# Keep getting an error "attempt to apply non function" when using an if statement

Tags: r

From a given data frame with a column State which has values P or F I am trying to create another column State1 which will have values 1 or 0 depending on whether State is P or F. 
The following is the code I wrote

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
    if (df$State(i)==P) {df$State1(i)<- 1} 
    else {df$State1(i) <- 0}  
    }
```

However I keep getting the error "attempt to apply non function". My code seems very simple and I am not sure why I am getting non function error. 
Please help
Thanks
KS

Comment: try the line `df$State(1)`  - what does it give you?

Comment: You are getting this error because parenthesis are used for functions in R. So the syntax "df$State(i)" suggests that df$State is a function that you are calling with the arguments i.

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax is not correct. Should be:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
    if (df$State[i]=="P") {df$State1[i] <- 1} 
    else {df$State1[i] <- 0}  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fridolin Linder provided the correct syntax. You can also do this with a much shorter command using the ifelse function that is vectorized

```
df$State1 <- ifelse(df$State == "P", 1, 0)
```

Comment: Or just `df$State == "P"` should be fine or at least `as.integer(df$State == "P")`

Comment: Yeah but that's a bit of a hack that doesn't generalize very well.